# installation ng2-search-filter recommend

Tags: angular, angular-material

do you have a recommendation beside of ng2-search-filter?
cause i got an error about this one `'Ng2SearchPipeModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)`
`ng2-filter.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ng2-search-filter) which declares Ng2SearchPipeModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.`
this is the error i got.

im using angular 12

Comment: Please don't write normal text with all upper-case. It's considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the pipe using the code in this comment, it works with angular 9+

https://github.com/solodynamo/ng2-search-filter/issues/55#issuecomment-607651243

demo here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yb5xd2?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.ts,src%2Fapp%2Finput-overview-example.html

Comment: can i apply this to the mat-table?